# \NewDocumentCommand and pagecounter

Tags: xparse, pageslts

I have tried to write a program that will let users input a file as an appendix. These pages should be numbered with roman numbers. It has worked well, but now I am trying to make an improvement: If the user do not have an appendix I would like the pagecounter to be set to zero. My approach was to set a counter to zero and have it updated in the document command. I can see that I have missed something, but I cannot find out what. Can someone direct me to a solution?
Here is an example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pageslts}

\newcounter{Appcount}
\setcounter{Appcount}{0}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\app}{m}
{
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\itshape Side \, \thepage\ av \, \lastpageref{pagesLTS.roman}}
    \appendix

    \section*{Vedlegg}
    \input{#1}

    \setcounter{Appcount}{\lastpageref{pagesLTS.roman}}

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


    \app{filename.tex} %can be left out

    Number of pages in the appendix: \theAppcount
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should mention what doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, what doesn't work is that the \setcounter{Appcount}{\lastpageref{pagesLTS.roman}}. The counter will always be zero, but the number of pages shown in the appendix is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\lastpageref{pagesLTS.roman}` is not a number and can not be used in a `\setcounter`. You can try the refcount package and the label `pagesLTS.roman.local` provided by pageslts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcounter{Appcount}
\setcounter{Appcount}{0}
\usepackage{refcount}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\app}{m}
{
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\itshape Side \, \thepage\ av \, \lastpageref{pagesLTS.roman}}
    \appendix

    \section*{Vedlegg}
    \input{#1}
    \setcounter{Appcount}{\getpagerefnumber{pagesLTS.roman.local}}

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


    \app{test3.tex} %can be left out

    Number of pages in the appendix: \theAppcount
\end{document}
```